# Word for the point where you can feel the music throughout your body

Tags: single-word-requests

When you are listening to music and you continue to turn the volume up, there is a certain point where you just sorta feel "full" of the music. It is a fabulous feeling. Is there a specific word for this?

I thought nirvana may apply but I wasn't sure.

Comment: *Ouchmyearsarebleeding*? Or *callmybrokerandbyhearingaidstock*? Not that I don't like some music so loud that you can feel it, but it is very bad for your hearing.

Comment: Umm, "nirvana" is a word with a specific meaning in Buddhist theology that has nothing to do with music. It has acquired a general meaning of "feeling of extreme well-being", that has, as far as I can figure out, nothing to do with the Buddhist meaning. I suppose you could use it to describe your feeling about music, but it's certainly not specific to that.

Comment: I'm not talking about _that_ loud. I mean like 90 decibels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Eleven**, as in "*[These go to eleven](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088258/quotes)*."

You'd probably enjoy [these songs](http://www.npr.org/2011/11/09/142134677/these-go-to-eleven-songs-best-heard-extra-loud), then.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say ***my body is vibrating to the music***.

Comment: I call it, "The point just before my head explodes."

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you have reached the point of *corporal resonance*... but I don't think there's any specific word for such a feeling.